# Display multiple 2D plots in 3D using Graphics in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, 3d, wolfram-mathematica

Considering the following :

```
lalist = {{{{1, 1}, 1}, {{3, 3}, 1}, {{5, 5}, 1}},
          {{{1, 5}, 1}, {{3, 3}, 1}, {{5, 1}, 1}}}
```

[image]

```
Row[{
  Graphics[{
            Opacity[0.5],Red, 
            Disk @@@ lalist[[1]]}, 
            Frame -> True],
  Graphics[{
            Opacity[0.5],Blue, 
            Disk @@@ lalist[[2]]}, 
            Frame -> True]}
    ]
```

[image]

- Is it possible that I plot the Blues
  Disks "behind" the red ones in a 3 D
  plot ?

Below is not what I need :

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

```
Graphics3D[{{Texture[
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Blue, Disk @@@ lalist[[2]]}, 
  Frame -> True]], 
 Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates \[Rule] {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
    1}}]}, {Texture[
 Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Red, Disk @@@ lalist[[1]]}, 
  Frame -> True]], 
Polygon[{{-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates \[Rule] {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
    1}}]}}, Lighting \[Rule] "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Lots of them with opacity .2:

```
tab = Table[{Opacity \[Rule] .2, 
Texture[Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Blue, Disk @@@ lalist[[2]]}, 
  Frame -> True]], 
Polygon[{{-1, -1, z}, {1, -1, z}, {1, 1, z}, {-1, 1, z}}, 
 VertexTextureCoordinates \[Rule] {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
    1}}]}, {z, -2, 2, 1}];
plt = Graphics3D[{tab}, Lighting \[Rule] "Neutral"]
```

[image]

and 400 don't seem to be much of a problem in terms of speed (you can easily modify the code above to see it).

EDIT: OK, just to be silly, try this

```
Dynamic[Graphics3D[{{Texture[#], 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates \[Rule] {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
      1}}]}, {Texture[Rotate[#, \[Pi]/2]], 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates \[Rule] {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 
      1}}]}}, Lighting \[Rule] "Neutral"] &@Binarize[CurrentImage[]]]
```

which gives

[image]

(or something like that), rotatable, updated in real time etc.

Comment: @acl, sorry, no I had that, I really want a 3D plot :) How could I better express my question ?

Comment: @acl, Yes, do you think it could handle 400 of them :) ?

Comment: @acl ! Thank You ! How can I get it to be transparent so that we only see the shapes ? yet if you look at one you can`t see the other behind it?

Comment: @acl, Spot On ! Awesome, gives me a lot to play with !

Comment: @acl This is probably a graphics driver issue, but I don't get your latest figure in the same way. I get a tower with four empty layers. Removing the `Opacity \[Rule] .2` part gets me the four levels back, but then they are non-transparent. I've had that issue before with the transparency examples in the Texture docs, but after updating my drivers they worked. I've been trying them again, but now they don't work. It's almost like my drivers have been restored to their original state. Strange...

Comment: @acl, Sir, I did not pay attention to your latest code, I just thought it was a picture. I just spent 30 minute playing with it. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 9):

See the solution presented on "Lunchtime Playground: Fun with Mathematica" here: http://mathgis.blogspot.com/2009/02/howto-display-2d-plot-in-3d.html

Answer (score 4):

Using transparent textures to render these circles in layers [as ACL does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486907/display-multiple-2d-plots-in-3d-using-graphics-in-mathematica/6486926#6486926) is a nice solution, unless one wants to interact with the resulting 3D object. [Rendering of 3D objects that contain transparent elements is done in software whereas otherwise it would have been done in hardware](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html):

> The 3D renderer uses two different
>   methods of sorting polygons. For
>   graphics scenes that include no
>   transparency, a hardware-accelerated
>   depth buffer is used. Otherwise, the
>   renderer uses a binary space partition
>   tree to split and sort polygons from
>   any viewpoint. The BSP tree is slower
>   to create and is not hardware
>   accelerated, but it provides the most
>   general ability to support polygons.

On my laptop, interaction  with 3D graphics is incredibly slow as soon as transparent objects start to appear.

The solution would be to use 3D disks instead of semi transparent planes with 2D disks in them. Since MMA doesn't have 3D `Disk`s or `Circle`s if you want to do something like that, you have to roll your own. A bare-bones version would be something like:

```
myDisk[{x_, y_, z_}, r_] := 
 Polygon@Table[
               {x, y, z} + r {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]], 0} // N,
               {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/200}
              ]
```

Your layers would then be generated as follows:

```
Graphics3D[
 {
   EdgeForm[],
  {
   Red, 
   myDisk[{1, 1, 0.5}, 0.5],  
   myDisk[{0, 0, 0.5}, 0.5],   
   myDisk[{-1, -1, 0.5}, 0.5]
  },
  {
   Blue,  
   myDisk[{1, -1, -0.5}, 0.5],
   myDisk[{0, 0, -0.5}, -0.5], 
   myDisk[{-1, 1, -0.5}, 0.5]}
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: ah, but my polygons have my face on them!

Comment: @ACL yeah, I tried your code too. Makes for some criminal looking, rather unrecognizable portraits. Just great for avatars. (Do you wear turtleneck sweaters and a beard, BTW?)

Comment: in any case you're right, `Opacity` does slow things down even on my macbook with its pathetic graphics card.

Comment: (about the turtleneck and beard, I noticed that too; never even touched a turtleneck and shaved the beard when I finished my PhD in 2005...)

Comment: @acl I had one the year before I finished my PhD. Makes one wonder what the other guys here (didn't see much gals around) did.

Comment: @sjoerd of course, when you got your phd i was just starting school :) BTW I was in ITF Utrecht for 2 years (left last year). funny, no?

Comment: @Sjoerd, Thank You very much ! I actually came to do that last night but could not figure out how to make Disks !

Comment: +1 I like the look of this one best, and it even works on version 7!