# See a Graphics3D Straight in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica, 3d

Considering Sjoerd Solution on [displaying multiple 2D plots in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486907/display-multiple-2d-plots-in-3d-using-graphics-in-mathematica) :

```
myDisk[{x_, y_, z_}, r_] :=

Polygon@Table[
             {x, y, z} + r {Cos[\[Phi]], Sin[\[Phi]], 0} // N, 
             {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi]/200}
             ]

Graphics3D[
 {
   EdgeForm[],
  {
   Red, 
   myDisk[{1, 1, 0.5}, 0.5],  
   myDisk[{0, 0, 0.5}, 0.5],   
   myDisk[{-1, -1, 0.5}, 0.5]
   },
   {
   Blue,  
   myDisk[{1, -1, -0.5}, 0.5],
   myDisk[{0, 0, -0.5}, -0.5], 
   myDisk[{-1, 1, -0.5}, 0.5]}
   }
   ]
```

Using ViewPoint I get :

[image]

Whereas I would like to systematically see :

[image]

Any Idea ?

Comment: "God does not play dice with the universe." AE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A combination of `ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}`, and `ViewPoint -> Top`?

Answer (score 2):

[ViewMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewMatrix.html) (look at Basic Examples)

Answer (score 1):

How about `ViewPoint -> Top` ?

Comment: Ah, I see the right one is using that, but has been rotated somehow.  I bet deleting the output cell entirely will and re-evaluating will fix that.